# How block USB Ports in windows using vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

am new in`vb.net` programming, am developing an experimental application to block `USB` ports in `windows` computers,it can be possible by editing some values in `regedit` as am new in programming i am totally blank, any help will much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- first import the following

> `Imports Microsoft.Win32`

- Function to disable/Block

  ```
  Private Sub functionToBlock()
      Dim regKey As RegistryKey
      regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR", True)
      regKey.SetValue("Start", 4) //' 4(To disable the ports)
  End Sub
  ```
- Function to Enable/Unblock

  ```
  Private Sub functionToUnblock()
     Dim regKey As RegistryKey
     regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR", True)
     regKey.SetValue("Start", 3) //' 3(To enable the ports)
  End Sub
  ```

Answer (score 0):

below is the solution which is working for 32 bit windows but not working 64 bit ...

//disable USB storage...

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR", "Start", 4, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

//enable USB storage...

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR", "Start", 3, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```